# Cloud-based WMS service: transactions estimator?

Tags: wms, cloud-gis

My organization is quite a medium-large organization (5,000 employees) and is facing some severe budget cuts. Resources are sparse and we are looking at using cloud-based service for our Base-mapping tiles as we do not have the resources to update and cache base-maps internally, let alone regularly.
The cloud-based services look appealing due to the fact that data management is done elsewhere and base-maps are always up-to-date without us having to do anything.
Of course it comes at a cost, and the cost varies based on number of usage / **tile transactions per year.**

At the moment, GIS usage is limited to a certain number of staff within the organization and is only desk bound. We are rolling mobiles and will allow **all** our staff to access our web-mapping applications, so usage will probably dramatically increase. I have no idea how I can work out the oragnisation's yearly usage in order to build a business case to procure such a service or even compare it with paying consultants to create a cache for us and internally serve it.

Is there a way of estimating the tiles used based on the size of the area my organization cover and the number of staff??
I can't find a tool which helps calculate that. Does anybody know of a good methodology?

Comment: Need more info: are you using Open Source or ESRI? Where is the hosting? Azure, AWS or Openshift?

Comment: @Dan, the OP is asking for an approach to estimate tile consumption, not the actual cost over a year. Assuming 256x tile sizes, I expect tile consumption is _mostly_ vendor/setup-agnostic.

Comment: @elrobis Agreed sort of..OP is steering there with saying "facing some severe budget cuts"..but he may find that its a non issue based on his environment.  Take for example ESRI "transaction is equivalent to eight 256 x 256 tile requests" but  limited to 50million a year...does Geoserver (assuming this is what OP is using) even have a limit?

Comment: Geoserver is just software. So if you're admin'ing your own Geoserver, transactions are irrelevant--providing your web host does not govern I/O. Mapbox, however, provides a cloud-based service like the OP describes, and they [`measure a single map view as 15 raster map tiles`](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-map-view/). The way I see it, though, "guesstimating" how many tiles an organization's users are going to consume in a year's time, collectively, is the lowest common denominator to all of this, and vendor/setup will be irrelevant to any reasonable approach to derive that value.

Comment: Hi, We're UK based and currently an ESRI company. However we may need to review our vendor under EU procurement rules, so we could be changing. This is why I was tending for a WMS / WMTS feed served by an external company (examples in the UK are OS on Demand, viaEuropa... and plenty of others including ESRI, Cadcorp...etc). By using external providers we are more resilient for change. But prices varies on the number of transactions (i.e. tiles used per year)... but my concern is how do we know how much we would be consuming tto be able to plan for our budget appropriately.